# How to pass a value based on the input value chosen on a radio button?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to switch between two arrays to perform some calculations based on the choice from radio button. To do this, I have two radio buttons with common name property, and by default, I have No option checked on html.

```
<div class="control">
  <label for="Yes">
    <input id="Yes" name="ip" type="radio" value="Yes" />
    Yes
  </label>
  <label for="No">
    <input id="No" name="ip" type="radio" value="No"  checked />
    No
  </label>
</div>
```

I am passing array_one and when the user checks the Yes radio button, it needs to switch to array_two and use the values to calculate. How do I get this to work. What am I missing?

```
var array_one = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var array_two = [2,3,4];
var age = 20;

var rates = array_one;

function calculate(){
    var outputA = rates[age-16] *  68000 / 1000;
   $('#ip').html("$" + outputA);
}


if($("input[name=ip]:checked").val() == 'Yes') {
  rates = array_two;
  console.log($("input[name=ip]:checked").val());  
  calculate();
}else{
 calculate();
}
```

I have provided the link to JSfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/p0um5v7e/9/

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function() {
  banner.addClass("alt")
})

var array_one = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var array_two = [2, 3, 4];
var age = 20;

var rates = array_one;

function calculate() {
  var outputA = rates[age - 16] * 68000 / 1000;
  $('#ip').html("$" + outputA);
}


if ($("input[name=ip]:checked").val() == 'Yes') {
  rates = array_two;
  console.log($("input[name=ip]:checked").val());
  /* var array_one = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
  var array_two = [2,3,4];
  var age = 25; */

  banner.addClass("alt");
  calculate();
} else {
  calculate();
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
<div class="control">
  <label for="Yes">
    <input id="Yes" name="ip" type="radio" value="Yes" />
    Yes
  </label>
  <label for="No">
    <input id="No" name="ip" type="radio" value="No"  checked />
    No
  </label>
</div>
<div id="ip">

</div>
```

Comment: You need to put the code inside an event listener so it runs when the user checks one of the buttons.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen to the change event of the radio buttons and trigger the recalculation. You can also move the radio button check inside that function.

Additionally, you need to add some kind of fallback in case `age - 16` is a value outside of the index range of the array used (otherwise, it would result in `"$NaN"`). I assumed a value of 0 in this example, but you might need to adapt that to your needs.

```js
var array_one = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var array_two = [2, 3, 4];
var age = 20;

function calculate() {
  var rates = $("input[name=ip]:checked").val() === 'Yes' ? array_one : array_two;
  var outputA = (rates[age - 16] || 0) * 68000 / 1000;
  $('#ip').html("$" + outputA);
}

$("input[name=ip]").on('change', function() {
  calculate();
});

calculate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control">
  <label for="Yes">
    <input id="Yes" name="ip" type="radio" value="Yes" />
    Yes
  </label>
  <label for="No">
    <input id="No" name="ip" type="radio" value="No"  checked />
    No
  </label>
</div>
<span id="ip"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code bellow:**

I am changing some javascript code your previous code here

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function() {
  banner.addClass("alt")
})

var array_one = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var array_two = [2, 3, 4];
var age = 20;

var rates = array_one;
calculate($("input[name=ip]:checked").val());

function calculate(val) {
  console.log(val);
  if(val=='yes'){
     //your action when yes
  }else {
     //your another action when no
  }
  
  var outputA = rates[age - 16] *( 68000 / 1000)
  $('#ip').html("$" + outputA);
}

$('[name="ip"]').on('change', function() {
   calculate($("input[name=ip]:checked").val());
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
<div class="control">
  <label for="Yes">
    <input id="Yes" name="ip" type="radio" value="Yes" />
    Yes
  </label>
  <label for="No">
    <input id="No" name="ip" type="radio" value="No"  checked />
    No
  </label>
</div>
<div id="ip">

</div>
```

Comment: Hi Abu,  Thanks for the quick reply, tried this but getting to work on one condition only. it is able to pick the value changes however it is passing only the array when it is Yes. When it is No the array_one is not getting picked

if(val=='yes'){
     //your action when yes
    rates=array_two;
  }else {
     //your another action when no
     rates=array_one;
  }